# How do I repair this exterior window trim?

Tags: wood, exterior

[image: shot to show scale]
[image: close shot 1]
[image: close shot 2]
[image: close shot 3]

I have a few thin cracks in a wooden exterior window sill. It doesn’t seem like the damage is too extensive (most of the wood seems sound and not rotten), so I wanted to try repairing it instead of replacing the whole things.

Any advice regarding the materials and process I should use? I was thinking 1) sanding, 2) some kind of wood filler (is the crack too small for this?), and 3) primer + paint.

Is a repair a good idea here? Should I use wood filler or caulk, and any product recommendation?

Thanks!

Comment: I've used auto body filler with good success for jobs like this.  You want the plain body filler, and not the kind with the fiberglass fibers in it.

Answer (score 5):

Scape the loose paint, coat with a product like [XIM Peel Bond](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/xim/primers-sealers/peel-bond), which will lock down the surrounding  area. It basically acts like a glue, for flaky paint. I have used this product extensively for this exact purpose and it works fantastic.

Once the Peel Bond is dry you can use some exterior wood filler, build it up and then sand/reshape it to where you are happy.

After that, paint as usual.

*Image Credit: Rustoleum*
[image: Peel Bond]